# How to get ISO 3166 Country Code from CultureInfo in .NET

Tags: .net, .net-core, cultureinfo, culture, iso-3166

Given a `CultureInfo` object, how do I get the two character ISO 3166 Country Code? E.g. from `en-US`, I want `US` and from `en-GB`, I want `GB`. I also need to handle cases where the culture may not have a country code.

Answer (score 5):

Use [RegionInfo-class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to retrieve two (or three) letter iso region name:

```
RegionInfo usa = new RegionInfo("en-US");           
string isoUSA = usa.TwoLetterISORegionName;

RegionInfo gb = new RegionInfo("en-GB");
string isoGB = gb.TwoLetterISORegionName;
```

You might want to catch possible exception that will happen if you try to pass invalid value to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ISOLib)

This library that provides access to ISO standards, including ISO 639 (language codes), ISO 3166 (country codes), and ISO 4217 (currency codes).

Example:

```
Country[] countries = Countries.Collection.Where(c => c.Name[0] == 'A').ToArray();
foreach (Country country in countries)
{
   Language[] langs = country.GetLanguages();
   Currency[] currencies = country.GetCurrencies();
   string langsColumn = string.Join(',', langs.Select(l => l.Name));
   string currenciesColumn = string.Join(',', currencies.Select(l=>l.Alpha3));
   Console.WriteLine($"{country.Alpha2};{country.Name};{currenciesColumn};{langsColumn}");
}
```